# Axiom of Choice as similar to Parallel Postulate?

Tags: geometry, logic, axiom-of-choice

I'm looking for resources that have drawn a comparison between the Parallel Postulate and the Axiom of Choice.

That is, if we treat ZFC as an analogue to Euclidean geometry, can we view the development of models of ZF that, for instance, exclude AC and CH, as being similar to geometries that exclude certain axioms of Euclidean geometry?

I haven't been able to locate any, but it's also a really tough idea to frame in academic journal search engines, and this is about the only result I can uncover in general searches: https://thetwomeatmeal.wordpress.com/2010/10/29/the-zermelo-fraenkel-axioms-for-sets/

Comment: Are you looking for a popular account, or a mathematics paper? Both statements are independent of the underlying axiomatic set, but that seems to be the only similarity. The most well-studied example of an alternative axiom to the Axiom of Choice is called the Axiom of Determinacy. There are many many papers on it, such as [this one](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-symbolic-logic/article/axiom-of-determinacy-implies-dependent-choices-in-lr/89D5A8B9741655942B9011CAC87BE932) (picked mostly at random).

Comment: There is _some_ fuzzy/soft similaity in that both AC and the parallel postulate are (1) claims that intuitively feel like they should be true, but (2) are somewhat more complex state than the simpler "fundamental" axioms the rest of the theory can be reduced to, (3) therefore people have been searching for a way to reduce them to simpler axiomatic truths, but (4) eventually this search terminated in the discovery that they're independent of the recognized simpler axioms.

Comment: Note that this narrative _doesn't_ say that we know there _cannot_ be a property that is equivalent to the axiom in question and is so simple to state that it would have been accepted as an axiom without all the attempts to prove it from other axioms. This seems rather unlikely in either of these cases, but we don't really have a good technical concept of what exactly "simple enough" would mean, so we can't even hope to _prove_ that it is so.

Comment: Stella, it seems far more likely to be discussed in a popular account; but any resource would be appreciated. The similarity you've identified is precisely what I'm looking for. I'm working on a general audience discussion of the early history of set theory, and want to draw a similarity between the parallel postulate & AC to give readers an idea of what the issue is/was and why mathematicians still declare when they're using AC, even though it's more or less accepted today.

Comment: The OP can correct me, but I think the OP is indeed looking for some more abstract parallel like Henning is pointing out, to which we can add that just as there are two separate branches for Euclidian and Non-Euclidian geometry, there are also two branches regarding the AC: one where AC is assumed to be true and one where AC is assumed to be false. Maybe the OP is interested in knowing more about that idea?

Comment: Bram28, Henning, this is indeed what I'm looking for; preferably in a publication of some sort; a discussion of how discarding the parallel postulate enriched geometry--and eventually had real-world application vis a vis Minkowski space-time--alongside a discussion of AC making similar points.

Comment: Well, non-euklidean geometry... ask Mercury for his perihelion, but I'm afraid it would be harder to find an application for set theory without the axiom of choice.

Comment: @ProfessorVector: That's not true. And isn't that what Hardy said about number theory just before modern cryptography came?

Comment: @StellaBiderman- didn't properly tag you in my reply above.

Comment: @Bram28, ditto.

Comment: The axiom of choice is nothing like the axiom of parallels in Euclidean geometry. The parallels postulate was considered an oddity because of its technical and unnatural formulation. The axiom of choice *is* natural (one could argue about technical, but it's not as technical as Replacement). If any of the ZFC axioms is the odd one out, it would be Foundation (Regularity). That's also the only axiom without much impact on "normal mathematics". It's an odd technical duck, which is very interesting from a set theoretic point and has opposites in Anti Foundation Axioms. But yeah, it's not as sexy.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila "That's not true" because...? Non-euklidean geometry in general relativity is present. I'm not saying there is no **potential** use of a set theory without an axiom of choice, but I'm not aware of an **actual** one. If there is, I'd be grateful for an example (and, believe it or not, I wouldn't mind to be wrong).

Comment: @ProfessorVector: I am currently on vacation, so I can't quite find you the exact term, but this is a Fraenkel–Mostowski construction (of choiceless models) that has applications in computer science, of all things. Since that is the OG choiceless construction, well, I'd say that choiceless set theory is not that useless.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila I'd be very much interested in that example. I'm a mathematician by education, but I'm mainly working with computers for the last 20 years or so.

Comment: @ProfessorVector: The term is "nominal sets". Some Polish bloke gave a nice talk about this in the Mostowski100 conference some years ago.